# std::swap causes infinite recursion in VS 2013

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
    foo()
    {
    }

    foo(foo&& other)
    {
        std::swap(*this, other);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    foo f(std::move(foo()));
}
```

It causes infinite recursion in VS2013, but fails to compile with g++/clang with errors that `operator=` is deleted (which makes sense):

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/utility:70,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h: In instantiation of 'void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = foo]':
main.cpp:11:26:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:186:11: error: use of deleted function 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)'
       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
           ^
main.cpp:3:12: note: 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)' is implicitly declared as deleted because 'foo' declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
     struct foo
            ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/utility:70,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/move.h:187:11: error: use of deleted function 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)'
       __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
           ^
```

I assume this is a VS bug. But does the standard impose any rules on how `std::swap` should be implemented? I mean is this simply a bad implementation in VS or a violation of the standard?

Comment: It seems reasonable for `swap` to move-construct via a temporary object.  It's more usual for `foo(foo&&)` to swap its _members_ with those of its argument.  i.e. `foo(foo&& other) { swap(member, other.member); }` etc

Comment: @TobySpeight yeah I know this is not the canonical way of implementing move constructors - I also usually choose the way you described, but when I stumbled upon this behavior in VS I was amazed:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code shouldn't compile because according to the C++14 standard draft N4140 [utility.swap]/2:

> *Requires:* Type `T` shall be `MoveConstructible` (Table 20) and `MoveAssignable` (Table 22).

C++11 contains the same requirement.

So this is indeed a bug in VS2013, and it's actually fixed in VS2015.

However, after adding a move assignment operator like this:

```
foo& operator=(foo&& other) = default;
```

you'll get infinite recursion in GCC, Clang and VS2015 ([DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fac9f9e0d798d1a3)).

One could easily guess that since `swap()` requires `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`, it uses move constructor and/or move assignment operator inside, so it's definitely illegal to implement them via calling `swap()` for `this` and parameter.